# Interpolate variables in environment variables definition with docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I interpolate env vars when using docker-compose . if I have a following vars.env file :

```
VAR_1=value_1
VAR_2=value_1/value2
VAR_3=value_1/value3
```

I would like to interpolate using of VAR_1 like this

```
VAR_1=value_1
VAR_2=${VAR_1}/value2
VAR_3=${VAR_1}/value3
```

But it is not working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported. You can however use an `.env` file to set the value of `$VAR_1`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/