# Link Docker ENV variables

Tags: docker, variables, environment-variables

I have 2 ENV files, one global and one for the container...

1.env

```
DockerPath=/mnt/appdata/docker
```

2.env

```
name=traefik
ContainerPath=$DockerPath/$Name
```

The files are called via the docker-compose file.

```yaml
    env_file:
        - ../1.env
        - ./2.env
```

this works fine.

But the variable `$ContainerPath` does not contain the correct path...
it should have `'/mnt/appdata/docker/traefik'`
Just now i didn't find a solution for it.

Can someone tell me how to link the two variables in the ENV file?

Comment: If this was in a Compose `environment:` block, I'd expect the rule to be that `key=${var}` references got values from the _host's_ environment and not other environment variables in the image or container; I wonder if this is also true here.

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699288/interpolate-variables-in-environment-variables-definition-with-docker-compose-ym) it's not possible